# Synchronous data calls in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, synchronization, ember-data

I am trying to do the following when visiting reviews/show (`/reviews/:id`):

- Load two models from the server: One `review` and one `user`.
- I only have access to the `review`'s id, so I need to load it first, to get the `userId`
- And then, when that has finished loading and I now have the `userId`, query the `user` using the `userId` attribute from the `review`
- Finally, return both of these in a hash so I can use them both in the template

So two synchronous database queries, and then return them both at once in the `model` hook of the route.

I don't mind if it's slow, it's fast enough for now and I need it to work **now**.

This is what I've tried and it doesn't work:

reviews/show.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var user;
    var review = this.store.findRecord('review', params.id).then(
      function(result) {
        user = this.store.findRecord('user', result.get('userId'));
      }
    );

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      review: review,
      user: user
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: By the way, you're doing **chained** data calls. Synchronous ajax calls block javascript from executing anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var reviewPromise = this.store.findRecord('review', params.id);
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      review: reviewPromise,
      user: reviewPromise.then(review => {
        return this.store.findRecord('user', review.get('userId'));
      })
    });
  }
});
```

The reason why user is `undefined` is because it hasn't been assigned in your first promise until the review is resolved, but Ember.RSVP.hash has received `user` as `undefined`.

Comment: Hey Kit. Thanks for your answer.
When you run the code exactly as you've posted, it gives an error `cannot read property 'store' of undefined` .. because the context of `this` changes inside the promise. It can be fixed by saving `this` to a variable inside the `model()` scope. But you had exactly the right idea. I edited the answer so that it has working code (PS i only edited your comments about being nice so I would have at least 10 characters in my edit, sorry haha)

Comment: @MarcoPrins The context doesn't change when you use an arrow function. Make sure you didn't type out `function`

Comment: that's interesting.. Is it an ES6 thing?

Comment: @MarcoPrins Yeah, check this out https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/ All of that works when you're using **ember-cli**